# Различия работы requests (python) в Windows и Linux?

Tags: python, requests

Всем доброго времени!
Люди добрые, помогите решить вопрос! Есть такой код

```js
import requests


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'navigate',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'none',
    'Sec-Fetch-User': '?1',
}

response = requests.get('https://www.cian.ru/sale/flat/278196886/', headers=headers)

print(response.status_code)
```

В Ubuntu он отлично отрабатывает и вернет код 200 и содержание страницы! Но вот в Windows получаю ошибку 503.
С чем это может быть связанно? Я предполагаю, что модуль requests в Windows работает иначе, чем в Linux. Так ли это?

Comment: в Windows тоже 200 код выдает

Comment: Какая у вас версия?
На 7 и 10 ошибка 503

Comment: Windows 11 у меня, но не думаю, что это из-за винды

Comment: подтверждаю ошибку с кодом 503 на win 10